# iptable nat forwarding

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I am having three linux PCs ( A B and C )in a LAN . I want to keep A as a client and send request to B . B in turn should forward the request to C and C should return back to B and finally B to A .

In short A should get the content of C through B .

i have used the following IP table in B

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination C
```

After this , the packets from A to B are reaching C .

Now I want ,

1. C to reply to B without directly replying to A .
2. B to reply to A with the content of C .

What should i do ?

Note : I have enabled ip_forward also .

kindly help .

Answer (score 0):

Add following rule to B (I assume eth1 is the interface facing C):

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -o eth1 -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source B

Alternative:

iptables -A POSTROUTING -t nat -d C -p tcp --dport 80 -j SNAT --to-source B

It will translate source address of the packet being forwarded (originally A) to B.